# How to push an array into an array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have 2 arrays in `JS` that holds values of longitudes and latitudes. I want to create dynamic variable locations which holds data corresponding to these arrays. Note that the size of these arrays changes each time (depending on the user).

**Arrays that I want to push into locations array:**

- `longi_array` holds all longitude values
- `lati_array` holds all latitude
  values

Now, I'm trying to create a dynamic variable locations (which is an array of arrays) the size of which depends on how many elements are currently in latitude and longitude arrays.

This is my code:

```
var locations = [];
for (var i = 0; i < lati_array.length; i++) { 

      locations.push(['<h4>Some Beach</h4>', lati_array[i], longi_array[i]]);
  });
```

This is not working. I do not get an error message. Netbeans does not show any syntax errors. The behavior that I was expecting was that locations was supposed to now hold an array of arrays that would help me plot place markers on Google maps. It works if I insert each array value manually into the locations array, but when I try to do it dynamically, the google maps doesn't show up at all -- which means there's something wrong with locations array.

It seems like I'm making some mistake while trying to push the array into the location array. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Explain how is it not working. Edit the question and include the error message. This also does not seem like it has anything to do with PHP.

Comment: "This is not working." What behaviour are you expecting? What error do you receive (if any)?

Comment: Do the two arrays of latitudes and longitudes have the same length?

Comment: Fix this on end `});` to be `}`. That is only error in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to replace `});` by `}` and it work :

Hope this helps.

```js
var locations = [];
var lati_array = [1,2,3,4,5];
var longi_array = [11,22,33,44,55];

for (var i = 0; i < lati_array.length; i++) {
      locations.push(['<h4>Some Beach</h4>', lati_array[i], longi_array[i]]);
}

console.log(locations);
//Output : [Array[3], Array[3], Array[3], Array[3], Array[3]]
```